# What is the connection string to connect to local db file (.mdf)

Tags: sql-server, qt5

I use the following connection string to connect to database in the sqlserver instance `SQLEXPRESS`:

```
QString connStr = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;";
```

But I want now to connect to SQL Server database file (.mdf) and I already installed Microsoft SQL Server 2016 LocalDB. What connection string should I use?

---

I tried the following connection string:

```
QString connStr = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;AttachDbFileName=%2;"
db.setDatabaseName(connStr.arg("(LocalDB)\\v11.0",dbFilename));
```

And I also tried a different server:

```
db.setDatabaseName(connStr.arg("(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB",dbFilename));
```

But none of them works and throw the same error:

> "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not
>   exist or access denied. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). QODBC3: Unable to
>   connect"

Comment: check out https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I already checked it, Qt has a different style of connection string. I tried different connection strings but none worked for me.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. If question is not clear enough plz tell me.

Comment: please show us the actual connection string you use for the localdb

Comment: @Squirrel -I've updated the  question.

Comment: Any updates ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I found the solution:

1- Ensure that Microsoft SQL Server 2016 LocalDB is installed.

2- Change the 'Driver' in the connection string to:

```
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}
```

3- Ensure the attribute 'AttachDbFileName' points to the correct database file path, especially you need to pay attention to the path separator whereas QT use "/" but in Windows you have to use "\" ("\\") <-- (This is was my main problem).

To get rid of this problem use `QDir::toNativeSeparators(dbFilename)`.

So and after those changes the connection string will be like this:

```
QString connStr = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=%1;AttachDbFilename=%2;Integrated Security=true;";
db.setDatabaseName(connStr.arg("(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB").arg(dbFilename));
```

Thanks.